# How to find the average of a count result in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, average

I'm suppose to get the AVG from the count results.

```
SELECT labelname AS Record_Labels, COUNT(title) AS Number_of_CDs_Released FROM CD
JOIN RecordLabel ON labelname = released_by
GROUP BY labelname;
```

I tried doing this: AVG(COUNT(title)), but it didn't work. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: I have tried Googling. But the answers given are all sub-queries, I want to try with JOIN.

Comment: That's because the logical way to do that is with a subquery.  Why do you want to use a join instead?  You didn't tried a join, you tried and failed with an aggregation.  The original question doesn't say one word about wanting to use join.

Comment: Ah yeah my bad for wording my question poorly. I've been practicing it with just JOIN, until recently started learning about subquery. So now I want to do my exercises not just with subquery but with JOINS as well, as I think it helps me understand SQL better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a nested query to do this:

```
select avg(Number_of_CDs_Released) from
(SELECT labelname AS Record_Labels, COUNT(title) AS Number_of_CDs_Released FROM CD
JOIN RecordLabel ON labelname = released_by
GROUP BY labelname) nested;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how do I do it so that it's AVG for each row of labelname instead of AVG of all label names?

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me.  You are doing counts for the unique labelnames.  Doing an average of one thing gives you that same thing - the count.  Doing an average of the whole table gives you an average of the counts.  Maybe you could go back and edit your original question with an example of what you actually want to do?

Comment: You saved me there, sorry. I read the question wrong, badly. I thought it asked me to find the AVG release of each record label, but it was just AVG of CDs released by record labels. It's been a long night of looking at codes :( I'd up your answer but I'm not allowed, however, I've ticked it. Thanks again!

Comment: Very Thanks! saved my day